# linux split file with incremental characters before extension

Tags: linux, bash

I want to split a large collection if text files. This is the script that i currently use

```
for file in *.txt
do
    split -b 120k "$file" "$file"_
done
```

When the input file is

hello_world.txt

the splitted files would be

```
hello_world.txt_AA
hello_world.txt_AB
hello_world.txt_AC
```

i want it to be like

```
hello_world_AA
hello_world_AB
hello_world_AC
```

How do i do it in linux ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, an expression of the form

```
${variable%suffix}
```

will expand to the contents of *`variable`* with the *`suffix`* removed from the end.

You can use this when you specify the new file prefix to `split` like this:

```
for file in *.txt
do
    split -b 120k "$file" "${file%.txt}"_
done
```